# Sorting the alphabets

Tags: java

I designed a program in Java for retrieving small letters from the given string. Now I want the in sorted order. How can i get a output in sorted order?

This is my code:

```
public class Smallalpha{

   public static void main(String []args){

      String s= "Hi aM hErE";
      int len =s.length();
      System.out.println("The lenth is "+len);
      for(int i=0;i<=len-1;i++){
        if(Character.isLowerCase(s.charAt(i)))
        {

                char alpha = s.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(alpha+" ");                
        }
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Store all letters in a list and user Collections.sort()

Comment: Try this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29

Answer (score 2):

Misunderstood your question in my now deleted first answer. This is what you can write, to have the program do what you want:

```
String s = "Hi aM hErE";
char[] chars = s.toCharArray(); // get the characters
Arrays.sort(chars);             // sort them
for (char c : chars) {          // print them, if they are lowercase
    if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
        System.out.print(c + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char%5B%5D%29) static method for this. Just call

```
String wors = "One two three";
String[] array = words.split(" ");
Arrays.sort(array);
```

or

```
char[] array = words.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(array);
```

depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "Hi aM hErE";
    int len = s.length();
    System.out.println("The lenth is " + len);
    ArrayList<Character> alpha = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) {
        if (Character.isLowerCase(s.charAt(i))) {
            alpha.add(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(alpha);
    System.out.println(alpha);

}
```

Try this.

Comment: Hi achintya can u explain reason for declaring another String str

Comment: @user1649845 I forgot to remove it.Now its fine. Thanks